# How to assign score on matching results in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, search, spring-data

I have following MongoDB document and i would like to assign score when each of the property is matched in full text search

```
  @Document
public class User {
    // there would be multiple industries and few or all could match, if any of the substring matched score is 40
    private String industries;
    // if there is any matching substring score is 10
    private String regions;
    // score is 20 on any match
    private String cities;
}
```

In the aggregation stages if it is a specific match i can check count and assign score but in full text search how i know which fields matched? and assign them related score?

Answer (score 0):

You wont know which fields matched but you can get sorted results based on weights assigned to the fields. When creating a index on the collection you can assign weights to the different fields in the collection and use sort or projections.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/

Comment: Weights and score works in a different way, if you assign a weight 40 to industries and if the whole string is matched the score would be 200 or more than 40, what i am looking here is to assign score of 40 or less on any match so maximum score should be 40

Comment: answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242769/percentage-of-or-conditions-matched-in-mongodb looks bit more relevant but that is to specific keys not based on full text search